# 3rd party drive or standard in a new MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

so I'm looking to buy a new 17'' Macbook Pro, but I'm having a hard time deciding if I should buy it with a solid state included, or buy my own and stick it in. I've heard that the Toshiba drives they put in (for $1100) aren't as good as some other drives you could buy for closer to $800. Is there any truth to this?  Any recommendations/links would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For something like this, I would always buy my own and put it in for two reasons:

1. cost
2. you get an extra drive to play with

You will find better deals on SSDs if you purchase your own. However, there is one reason you would want to go with the Apple-supplied drive:

1. TRIM support

That's about it. I guess, if you know and value what TRIM support is, you only have one choice. If you are fine putting in your own drive and don't value TRIM support, then you have other options.

Comment: Well, I've heard that there are ways to enable trim on third party drives.

Comment: I've heard the same, but I don't know if there is a reliable way to know if it is working correctly or not doing damage in some other way to the drive.

Comment: Well, what about the OCZ/OWC drives? They have TRIM built into hardware through the sandforce controller no?

Comment: Go for it. Honestly, that's what I would do. I'm already putting together the money to get an SSD for my MBP myself so I'm not being turned away.